# can't replace "powersaver" policy cpufrequtil

Tags: power-management, cpu

I downloaded cpufrequtil to change from the "powersaver" to the "performance" policy and I created a file by using:
    `nano /etc/default/cpufrequtils`
and I added this string to the new file:
    `GOVERNOR="performance"`
I then disabled the "ondemand" daemon but when I restarted the machine and inspected the CPU with `cpufreq-info`, it stated that I had indeed added the "performance" policy, but it was still using the "powersaver" policy.

How do I remove the "powersaver" policy?

EDIT: Xeon e3 1220v1

Comment: Is it an Intel CPU?

Comment: yes, it is Xeon e3

Comment: It makes no sense to set cpufreq for new Intel CPUs. Intel pstate controls them quite well and powersave is not worse that performance without pstate.

Comment: for my purposes it is, I have single threaded applications using 100% of a thread and the machine still is not using full clock speed